# Taking a pointer to a derived class ends in a runtime exception in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a simple abstract base class:

```
class Sensor {
protected:
    GenericDriver *driver;
public:
    Sensor() {};
    virtual void startNewReadout(void) = 0;
};
```

From which I derive a concrete class:

```
class OneWireSensor : public Sensor {
private:
    OneWireDriver oneWireDriver; //not really necessary here
public:
    OneWireSensor(PinData *pinData);
    void startNewReadout(void){
        this->driver->driverStartReadout();
    }
};
```

Now, when I use the below constructor, my code compiles and runs just as expected:

```
OneWireSensor::OneWireSensor(PinData *pinData) : oneWireDriver(OneWireDriver(pinData)) {
    this->driver = &oneWireDriver;
}
```

However, the field *oneWireDriver* is not used anywhere in my code and I don't want to set it. But when I remove it from the *OneWireSensor* class and use a constructor as follows:

```
OneWireSensor::OneWireSensor(PinData *pinData) {
    OneWireDriver oneWireDriver(pinData);
    this->driver = &oneWireDriver;
}
```

The code compiles fine **but the execution ends in a runtime exception** (a system hard fault since I am on embedded). GenericDriver is an abstract class from which OneWireDriver class inherits.
What am I doing wrong in the second case?

Comment: The `oneWireDriver` member *is* used, but under its alias `*this->driver`.

Comment: When you initiliase `this->driver` to point at `oneWireDriver`, and subsequent usage of `this->driver` does "use" `oneWireDriver`.     In your second code sample, `oneWireDriver` is local to the constructor, so ceases to exist when the constructor completes.   `this->driver` is therefore a dangling reference (points to an object that no longer exists) so using it causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused by the dangling pointer from the constructor of `OneWireSensor`.

```
OneWireSensor::OneWireSensor(PinData *pinData) {

    // A function local object.
    OneWireDriver oneWireDriver(pinData);

    // Pointer to the function local object.
    // It becomes a dangline pointer as soon as the function returns.
    this->driver = &oneWireDriver;
}
```

You need to use a dynamically allocated object.

```
OneWireSensor::OneWireSensor(PinData *pinData) {

    this->driver = new OneWireDriver(pinData);
}
```

But then you'll have to write code to manage the dynamically allocated memory. It'll be better to use a smart pointer instead of a raw pointer. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory for more on smart pointers.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing this out. Any suggestions on which smart pointer might be best for my application? I want the object to live forever in the program and be sure it's pointing to the right place

Comment: @Slighten,  Even though there is one object of type `OneWireDriver`, there are other considerations. You may use `std::unique_ptr` if you don't expect the pointer to be copied , i.e. the object that holds the pointer is not copied. If you execpt the pointer to be copied, go with `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

In the problem case `oneWireDriver` only exists when the constructor is running, then it goes out of scope. Using any pointers to it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the object here:

```
OneWireSensor::OneWireSensor(PinData *pinData) {
    OneWireDriver oneWireDriver(pinData); //<<<------
    this->driver = &oneWireDriver;
}
```

In the scope of the function.
Then you assign its address to a member of the class.

After the function scope ends, the `oneWireDriver` variable is destroyed. Now the class have a dangaling pointer to nowhere. At some point of the execution you probably try to dereference it hence the RuntimeException.

You need to make sure that the variable will live on after the function will end.
You can allocate it on the heap, you need to remember to deallocate on the destructor.